# Cardinality of all linear transformations from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried to calculate the cardinality of all linear transformations from $\Bbb R ^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$.

**This is my answer-  I would like to know how to formalize it better.**

A transformation is defined in a unique way on the basis elements.

Let $B_1=\{\bar v_1, \bar v_2,\bar v_3\}$ be a basis of $\Bbb R ^3$ and $B_2=\{\bar u_1, \bar u_2\}$ be a basis of $\Bbb R ^2$.

Any element in the codomain of the transformation is a linear combination of $\bar u_1, \bar u_2$. The number of different linear combinations of two elements is $\aleph^2$,
 so in the construction of a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ , every $v_i \space (i=1,2,3)$ can be matched with $\aleph^2$ different elements of $\Bbb R^2$.

Since there are 3 elements in $B_1$, there are $(\aleph^2)^3=\aleph^6=\aleph$ possible ways to construct $T$.

Therefore, the cardinality of all linear transformations  from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$ is $\aleph$.

What do you think? Is the reasoning right? Is there another way to think about it?

Comment: @Noah: It's a notation for $2^{\aleph_0}$. Not uncommon, too. I'm surprised that you didn't know that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, I've not seen it before. Good to know!

Comment: @Noah: I was taught this notation in my freshman year, and we were told that this is due to Cantor. I recently saw somewhere that it might be due to Hausdorff, though. *Edit.* [Here it is](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/why-did-cantor-and-others-use-mathfrakc-for-the-continuum).

Comment: You can make it shorter, if you know that $\;\mathcal L(\mathbf R^3,\mathbf R^2)\simeq\mathbf R^6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key reasoning is alright. It will be easier to note that after fixing the bases, every linear transformation can be represented by a $3\times 2$ matrix with real entries, and slide from there on a slightly clearer path.